# How can I pass multiple named parameters using ODBC to a DB2 database

Tags: db2, odbc, parameterized-query

I have to query a DB2 database using an existing ODBC connection. Executing simple queries works as expected, but as soon as I try to execute a parameterised query it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    ColumnA = ? AND
    ColumnB = ?
```

Using the `?` was suggested in other posts, but I always get empty results (no error messages though). When I try the standard SQL way with named parameters (and changing the SQL statement to `ColumnA = @ColumnA AND ColumnB = @ColumnB` as shown below

```
odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( ColumnA", 1234 );
odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( ColumnB", 9999);
```

the following error message is shown:

*System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S22] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0206N "@ColumnA" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703...*

Using `odbcCommand.Parameters.Add( new OdbcParameter( "ColumnA", Integer ){ Value = 1234 } );` instead shows that this is deprecated (and also doesn't work). I'd like to avoid using concatenated SQL statements, but I can't find a way to get parameterised queries working against a DB2 database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failed to mention your DB2 version. In DB2 9.7 and later there is a [driver parameter `DB2NETNamedParam`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0021005.html) that controls this behaviour. Check your `db2cli.ini` file.

I suspect that named parameters may not be supported in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to check the version when back at work.

Comment: It indeed seemed to be a version issue, although it took a while to find out and work around it.